# Solr: passing variable to update a field using POST

Tags: solr

I got stuck with the following Solr problem, while exploring document classification (using https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/SolrClassification as inspiration)

Having defined an `ExtractingRequestHandler` to load documents (txt and pdf files) in Solr, for the classification problem I need to augment the input with a categeroy label. I understand I could index the documents first and then using atomic updates add the label information in a second step. Also, I could somehow wrap the pdf / txt files in a JSON structure and supply the category label that way or use Data Import Handler. None of these solutions are ideal in my context.

Instead, I would prefer to pass the label as a variable / parameter while POST-ing documents (am on Windows using `post.jar`), but don't know how to adjust the `requestHandler` in `solrconfig.xml` to accept such custom defined parameters and use that as an input to the category field. All I could find was how to pass predefined parameters, but not how to add new ones and use them as inputs to fields.

Is this even possible, or would I have to write my own request handler for such a use case?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `literal.category=<your category>` in the URL?

Comment: Fabulous. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Credits to [@MatsLindh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/137650/matslindh)

The solution can't be simpler, using

`literal.category=<category_field>` in the URL

Can't believe I was not able to find it.